# Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined when using routeconfig

Tags: javascript, angular2-routing, angular2-meteor

I'm using the socially app tutorial to learn [Angular2](https://angular.io/) and [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). I've encountered a problem that I can't find the root cause of.

I'm following a [tutorial](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/routing-and-multiple-views) that states to add:

`RouteConfig` annotation:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { 
    path: '/', 
    as: 'PartiesList', 
    component: PartiesList 
  }, { 
    path: '/party/:partyId', 
    as: 'PartyDetails', 
    component: PartyDetails 
  }
]);
```

`router-outlet` in the app.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I get this exception when loading the app in Chrome:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in /client/app.html:0:0BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ 
modules.js?hash=12bd683…:59337BrowserDomAdapter.logGroup @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:59347ExceptionHandler.call @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:48750(anonymous function) @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54194ZoneDelegate.invoke @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:107413onInvoke @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54615ZoneDelegate.invoke @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:107412Zone.run @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:107306NgZoneImpl.runInner @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54646NgZone.run @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54538ApplicationRef_.run @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54183ApplicationRef_.bootstrap @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54205(anonymous function) @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:53993(anonymous function) @ meteor.js?
hash=ae8b8af…:1105ZoneDelegate.invoke @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:107413onInvoke @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:54615ZoneDelegate.invoke @ modules.js?
hash=12bd683…:107412Zone.run 

...

modules.js?hash=12bd683…:59337 TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' 
of undefined
at RouteRegistry.configFromComponent (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:87825)
at new RootRouter (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:87151)
at routerFactory (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:89570)
at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiate (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50544)
at ReflectiveInjector_._instantiateProvider (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50473)
at ReflectiveInjector_._new (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50462)
at ReflectiveInjectorDynamicStrategy.getObjByKeyId (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50117)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50642)
at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50614)
at ReflectiveInjector_.get (modules.js?hash=12bd683…:50423)
```

If I remove the `@RouteConfig` then no exception occurs but nothing is displayed obviously as no content is there to be presented. Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time now the angular and meteor time have came up with new versions which work out of the box at the time of writing. I also, by accident, figured out how to install a package. You can use the following format:

```
meteor npm install @angular/core
```

for example to install the angular core package

Answer (score 0):

@RouterConfig is only available for previous versions of router the deprecated and rc1. 
With the new release `3.0.0.apha.7` its no longer availabler. Read on the docs at [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

An example usage is

```
export const DashboarRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  ...
  e.t.c      
] 
export const routes: RouterConfig = [
...DashboardRoutes,
...UIRoutes
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
   provideRouter(routes)
];


APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS is then passed when bootstrapping main application
```

Comment: What command should I use to get the required new package? Tried your suggestion but the components are not resolved

Comment: Using the new router 3.0.0.apha.7, with the setup you have described above it seems the components are returning undefined. any ideas?

Comment: Yep, returning undefined.